# Does a reply to a wordpress comment notify the author of the comment?

Tags: comments

Currently I have my comments set so that when you hit "reply" to a comment, it will insert `@USERNAME` of the person you are replying to.  I am trying to find out if wordpress emails that user to let them know that I have replied to a comment they left or if this is something I will have to manually code in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't automatically send out emails. You can install a plugin to do that, however. There are quite a few listed in the WordPress plugin repository:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=reply+to+comment

Hope this helps, best of luck!